# What variables should be used to get correct information from LogisticRegression?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, logistic-regression

Every tutorial I have seen online has the LogReg variables as X_train, y_train. However, our professor had us split the test train data in a different program. We created a csv for both the test and train data and I have passed the csv into this program, but now I can't access the X_train, y_train variables so I don't know how use LogReg. Below is my code and thank you in advance for any help.

```
    # Read the training data
    print("Reading input...")
    df = pd.read_csv("train.csv", index_col=False)
    #print(df)
    data_numpy=df.values
    print(df.values)
    Y= df['TenYearCHD'].values
    #print(Y)
    X= df.iloc[:,:-1].values
    #print(X)
    #print(X.shape)

    print("Scaling...")
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    scaled_x = scaler.fit_transform(X)
    print(scaled_x)

    print("Fitting...")
    LogReg = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs', max_iter=2000)
    LogReg.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: If you had your data pre-split into separate files, then you read this in as train and test data respectively. Here you read `train.csv` as `df` and didn't split it. Read it as `train` and define `X_train` and `y_train` like you did, do the same with `test.csv`.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example